# Integral solution ,mild solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

What is the difference between "an integral solution" and " a mild solution" of a cauchy problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.